# C# - ref this (reference to self)

Tags: c#, reference, this

Suppose I have a code in C++:

```
class A {
    int x = 20;

    void Interact(A* Other) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) { Other->x++; x /= 2; } //some advanced operation
    }
public:
    void MakeInteraction(A* Other) {
        Interact(Other);
        Other->Interact(this);
    }
};

int main() {
    A a, b;
    a.MakeInteraction(&b);
}
```

Problem is, if I want to make something similar in C#, I meet the barrier - of course I don't need to use pointers, but I can't use reference to `this` object:

```
class A
{
    int x = 20;
    void Interact(ref A Other)
    {
        if (x % 2 == 0) { Other.x++; x /= 2; }
    }
    public void MakeInteraction(ref A Other)
    {
        Interact(ref Other); //works
        Other.Interact(ref this); //doesn't work
        Other.Interact(this); //still doesn't work
        A a = this; 
        Other.Interact(ref a);
        this = a; //REALLY? THIS DOESN'T WORK TOO?!
    }
}
```

I'm angry because I thought that C# corrects flaws of C++ and leaves as much options as originally C++, minus pointers. Now seems that switching from C++ to C# requires to change a way of thinking... again.

Comment: There is no "perfect" language. Each language has its own set of flaws. Don't think of C# as C++ minus pointers, because that's not true.

Comment: I don't expect it to be perfect, but I want to know how to avoid this exact problem.

Comment: Did you try to make Interact public?  How about static?

Comment: Can you explain what this code is meant to do?

Comment: This is just minimal example, it doesn't suppose to do anything besides changing value of parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use `ref` in your parameter declarations. For reference types like your `class A`, a parameter declared as just `A other` will cause C# to pass a reference to the object.

A parameter declared as `A other` in C# is similar to `A* other` in C++.

A parameter declared as `ref A other` in C# is similar to `A** other` in C++.

```
class A
{
    int x = 20;

    void Interact(A other)
    {
        if (x % 2 == 0) { other.x++; x /= 2; }
    }

    public void MakeInteraction(A other)
    {
        Interact(other);
        other.Interact(this);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        A b = new A();
        a.MakeInteraction(b);
    }
}
```